# Problemas de autenticación con .htaccess y .htpasswd

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Quiero asegurar mi proyecto de `Laravel` por medio de `.htaccess` y `.htpasswd`. Primero cree el archivo **.htpasswd** por medio del comando: `htpasswd -bc .htpasswd admin passadmin` En el directorio de mi subdominio personal */home/user/public_html*

Luego cree mi archivo **.htaccess** en el directorio */home/user/public_html/laravel_project* y las siguientes configuraciones

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Site Administratrion"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/public_html/.htpasswd"
Require user admin
```

Adicionalmente en mi archivo de configuración de `Apache` tengo la siguiente propiedad `AllowOverride All`

Testeando al acceder a mi URL personal me pide las credenciales del *.htpasswd*, ingreso a la pantalla de Login de mi aplicativo, accedo y me vuelve a solicitar las credenciales de *.htpasswd*, las ingreso de forma correcta pero no me deja ingresar y me arroja un **Error 401**:

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.

¿Por qué solicita credenciales de *.htpasswd* nuevamente al entrar al aplicativo?
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no me pida esos accesos al hacer login?
De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel por defecto trae ya los `.htaccess` preparados

```
 Options -Indexes

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteE

ngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# JWT
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]


# Redireccionar www a sin www
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

    # GZIP
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
                RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
        mod_gzip_on Yes
        mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
        mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
        mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


<IfModule mod_filter.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                          application/javascript \
                                          application/json \
                                          application/rss+xml \
                                          application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                          application/x-font-ttf \
                                          application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                          application/xhtml+xml \
                                          application/xml \
                                          font/opentype \
                                          image/svg+xml \
                                          image/x-icon \
                                          text/css \
                                          text/html \
                                          text/plain \
                                          text/x-component \
                                          text/xml
</IfModule>

## Cahe
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Solo tienes que añadir lo que te salio del `htpasswd -c /home/usuario/mipagina.com/carpeta/.htpasswd admin`

```
AuthUserFile /home/usuario/mipagina.com/carpeta/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Autentificacion"
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Relizando los mismos pasos me sigue solicitando credenciales luego del login. ¿Tiene que ver algo Laravel?

Comment: Depende de que login sea